# Formatting SD card using GParted does not allow it to be read using Mbed-os

Tags: filesystems, mbed

I am using Mbed-os to read data from a Micro SD card. However, when I format the disk using GParted (msdos MBR, 32MB fat16 partition), the SD card does not mount using the native Mbed libraries--`mount()` returns -22 (EINVAL: invalid argument). Looking into the source code of FATFileSystem.cpp, it looks like it could be caused by several factors, including: invalid path name (line 51), no valid FAT filesystem (line 65), or an ID that's not -1 (line 331). I don't know what these conditions really mean though.

However, when I format the SD card using Mbed, it works just fine and is able to be mounted just fine on my computer.

To mount my drive in Mbed, I'm using this code, hacked together from the [mbed documentation](https://os.mbed.com/docs/mbed-os/v5.10/apis/mbrblockdevice.html#mbrblockdevice-example):

```cpp
SDBlockDevice sd(
        D11,
        D12,
        D13,
        D10
    );

MBRBlockDevice part1(&sd, 1);
//ReadOnlyBlockDevice robd(&part1);
FATFileSystem fat("fat");

...


    if (sd.init() != 0) {
        printf("sd did not initialize\n");
        return false;
    }
    if (part1.init() != 0) {
        printf("part1 did not initialize\n");
        return false;
    }

    printf("fat mount: %d\n", fat.mount(&part1)); // fat.mount(...) returns -22 when I format the disk using gparted

    return true;
```

- How can I tell what differs between disk when I format it using Mbed versus when I format it with GParted? Is there a utility that gives me more information than fdisk?
- What is causing the GParted-formatted disk to error when mounting?

Here is the code that I'm using to format the disk:

```cpp
void format_disk() {
    printf("formatting...\n");
    MBRBlockDevice::partition(&sd, 1, 0x83, 0,  1024 * 1024 * 32);
    MBRBlockDevice part(&sd, 1);
    FATFileSystem::format(&part);
    printf("done?\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Mbed OS FATFileSystem is described as a FAT32 file system, but you're formatting as FAT16. I'm not sure if FAT16 and FAT32 are supposed to be compatible, but that would be my first guess.